# how do I run my code on cmd instead of vscode's internal terminal

Tags: c++, cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code, codeblocks

everyone. I'm kind of new in this field. So bear with it. I'll try to be as specific as I can:

let's say when I run a code(c++ file) in VScode it runs that code on VScode's internal terminal..like this => [VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3tHM.png)

but I want that code to run on my Window's CMD like "CodeBlocks" software. Like this => [CodeBlocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9jSA.png)

but I don't know how to do it in VScode. I mean, when I click on 'run' button it should execute that code on CMD. I tried many ways but it's not working. Help please and thanks in advance.

Comment: use [externalTerminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode has a **built-in terminal**. That is why in the first case(first image in your question) you see the output as it is. If you **don't want** to use the built in terminal provided by VSCode then i suggest you **open a standalone/separate** terminal. And then `cd` into the project you want to build/compile and then compile the program from there.

Basically, open a terminal externally then go(`cd`) to your workspace folder and finally compile and run in the external terminal.